# for ... next calculations not working properly in VB -- Homework

Tags: vb.net, loops

I cannot figure out why my calculation is not working.  I am doing for 1 to 12 and it gives me 12 inputs but counts my entries as 13?  What am I missing.

If I change it to 0 to 11 same thing.  I am not sure what the issue is, but I cannot see it, and am not sure where to look.

I need to end up with 12 cycles through and intEntries to be 12...  Help!  Thanks!

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        'initialize accumulator
        Dim decEntries As Decimal
        ' For loop to ask for input.
        For decEntries = 1 To 12 Or strMonthlyAvg = " "
            strMonthlyAvg = InputBox("Please Enter the Average for Month # " & decEntries & ":")

            lstTemps.Items.Add(strMonthlyAvg)
            decMontlyAvg = Convert.ToDecimal(strMonthlyAvg)
            ' This will add the montly average to the total Average Temperature for 
            ' calculations
            decTotalTemp += decMontlyAvg

        Next
        ' Calculation to provide the average temp for all entered values
        decAnnualAvg = decTotalTemp / decEntries
        ' convert annual average to string
        strAnnualAvg = Convert.ToString(decAnnualAvg)
        ' Display the results for the user
        lblResults.Text = "The average annual temperature " & vbCrLf &
                            "based on your entries is: " & strAnnualAvg & "."


    End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not famialir with an `Or` on the end of the `For` statement

Comment: After the 12th cycle, the Next will raise decEntries one more time. That is why it has 13. You could use a 2nd integer to catch this, or use a do while.

Comment: or divide by `lstTemps.Items.Count`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my answer to [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193511/my-accumulator-for-my-for-next-loop-is-skipping-numbers-in-vb-visual-studio) on this topic, whenever the loop hits the line:

```
Next
```

...it increments the counter `decEntries`.

So by the time it's gone round the loop for the 12th time, it finally comes to `Next` which adds 1 more to make the variable's value `13`. It then exits the loop because it has exceeded 12.

You could rewrite it using a `While` loop, which I'll let you investigate - or change your logic to take the final `Next` into account.

Comment: I couldn't get the do while loop to work either =(  Went with adding (decEntries - 1) to the logic.  Thank you for your help.